# Load next page in background by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a Bitcoin faucet rotator I have a js code but it's load only next page .But I want to call some details with page and the next page is loading in background.Like: (freebitcoin,100satoshi,60M)=show in header (next page is load complete)Next .
My Code is:

URLS.JS

```
var s=["url.com",
"url.com",
"url.com",
"url.com",
"url.com"
];
var adr,i,x=0,c=s.length;
function address() {
adr=prompt('Enter your bitcoin address:');
s=s.map(function(x){
  return x.indexOf("a=") != -1 ? x + adr : x; 
});
}
function next(){
x+=1;
if (x>c-1)
  {
  x=0;
  }
changeSrc();
}
function prev(){
x-=1;
if (x<=0)
  {
  x=c-1;
  }
changeSrc();
}
function jumpTo() {
i=prompt("Enter a number to skip to that faucet.");
x=0;
while (i!=x) {
  if (x>c-2) {
  break;
  }
  x+=1;
}
changeSrc();
}
function newTab() {
var win=window.open(document.getElementById("fm").src, '_blank');
win.focus();
}
function changeSrc() {
document.getElementById("fm").src=s[x];
}
```

Index.html

```
<a class="jone2" onclick='next()' href ='#'>NEXT</a>

<div class='col-2 frame'>
<iframe id="fm" name="fm" src="help.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```